# Count specific scheduled Sidekiq jobs with Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

Is there a way to use Redis to retrieve the following job count?

```
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.inject(0) do |memo, job|
  memo += 1 if job.at <= Time.now
  memo
end
```

I.e. jobs that are scheduled, should have been run already, but weren't. This works ok for smaller queue sizes but scales poorly for bigger ones (30+ seconds for 60k scheduled jobs). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Mike, I went with the following approach:

```
Sidekiq.redis { |c| c.zcount('schedule', '-inf', Time.now.to_f) }
```

Comment: Nice, I love users that can take my advice and improve it!

Answer (score 1):

```
"ZRANGEBYSCORE schedule '-inf' #{Time.now.to_f}"
```

https://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore

Comment: Legend. Thanks, Mike!